# IAM user security credentials not reflected in AWS credentials file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

**TL;DR:** *Is it possible to use the `AWS CLI` to update the locally stored `credentials` file with the IAM users information in my AWS account?*

I am following the instructions in this [AWS Amplify](https://docs.amplify.aws/start/getting-started/installation/q/integration/vue#option-2-follow-the-instructions) tutorial which includes these steps:

1. Creating an IAM user
2. Providing the IAM user credentials to the `amplify` CLI

Step 2 updated my local `\.aws\credentials` file to include a profile for the IAM user created in step 1.

After this, of my own accord, I went back into the IAM console and created a new `access key ID`.

This new access key is not included in my local `\.aws\credentials` file, so I would like to add it. *How can I do that?*

I have tried copying the profile entry created by the `amplify` CLI tool and pasting in the `aws_access_key_id` and `aws_secret_access_key`. However, I am not sure how to update the `toolkit_artifact_guid`. As I am creating a new profile for the same IAM user, *should I use the same `toolkit_artifact_guid`?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `aws configure` command can be used to add a new profile to your config

Use the `--profile` flag to create a profile in the `.aws/config` file.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/configure/

`toolkit-artifact-guid` is a piece of metadata used by tooling, such as extensions for an IDE. It is not required for specifying a new IAM profile